# Prove that $\exists a,b$ s.t. $a\mid b$ and $1<a<b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, divisibility

Let $p$ be a prime $>5$, Consider the set $S$ such that $$S=\{p-n^2 \mid p>n^2 \text{ and } n\in \mathbb Z^+\}$$
Show that $\forall p>5,\exists a,b\in S$ such that $a\mid b$ and $1<a<b$.

This problem is from the book Olympiad Number Theory Through Challenging Problem.

I tried several values of $p$ and they seem to work, I set this $$p-n^2\mid p-m^2,\quad m<n$$
But it didn’t work.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133390/discussion-on-question-by-yassir-prove-that-exists-a-b-s-t-a-mid-b-and-1).

Comment: It's a lovely question. You might like to just read the starts of the answers for the two cases and use these as hints to try the rest yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Our candidate for $a$ is going to be the smallest element of $S$ which is greater than $1$.

**CASE 1. If $p-n^2=1$**

Let $a=p-(n-1)^2=2n$ and $b=p-1^2=n^2$. Then $a|b$ since $n$ must be even.

N.B. If $a=b$ then $n=2$ which is why $p=5$ had to be excluded.

**CASE 2. If $p-n^2\ne 1$**

Let $a=p-n^2$ where $p<(n+1)^2$ and so $a<2n+1$.

Then the sequence $$p-1, p-4, ... , p-(n-1)^2$$ can be rewritten as
$$a+(n-1)(n+1), a+(n-2)(n+2), ... ,a+1(2n-1).$$
All the numbers from $1$ to $2n-1$, **other than $n$**, are factors of at least one of the numbers added to $a$ in this list. Therefore at least one of these numbers has the form $a+ta$ and is a multiple of $a$, unless $a=n$ or $2n$.

However, if $a=n$ or $2n$, then $p=n(n+1)$ or $p=n(n+2)$ and is not prime.